# Getting Error 500 Postman in a POST method

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

When I try to post JSON data via Postman I get an error 500.

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrrjw.png)

My JavaScript code

`

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const Crypto = require('crypto-js');
const { response } = require('express');

//  Create a registration

router.post('/rejestracja', async (req, res)=>{
    const nowyUser = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: Crypto.AES.encrypt(req.body.password, process.env.SEC_KEY).toString(),
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        surname: req.body.surname,
        username: req.body.username,
    });
    try{
        const newedUser = await nowyUser.save();
        res.status(201).json(newedUser);
    }
    catch(err){res.status(500).json(err)};
})
 
// Create a login

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        !user && res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        

        const securedPass = Crypto.AES.decrypt( user.password, process.env.SEC_KEY);
        const password = securedPass.toString(Crypto.enc.Utf8);
        
        password !== req.body.password && res.status(401).json("Email i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");
        
        response.status(200).json(user);
        console.log("dziala");
    } 
    catch(err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    
});


module.exports = router
```

I've checked and the error occurs after password !== req.body etc.

Registration works but login doesn't

Comment: A 500 error means there was an unexpected exception or error on the *server*. It may have been triggered by something in your POST request, but the software failure was on the server not the client.

Comment: try `res.status(500).json({message: err.message});` to see what is causing error.

Comment: @jkalandarov it gives me "message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')"

Comment: It seems like secret key is undefined here `process.env.SEC_KEY` can you confirm this.

Comment: @HarshMangalam it's defined in .env

Answer (score 0):

`!user && res.status(401).json("i/lub hasło jest nieprawidłowy");`
You're setting 401 status here, but the script execution goes on, and a few lines further you're accessing `user.password` anyway, and if user is null/undefined, that'll cause an error.

Maybe put an early return statement.